# formulate URLs for application which are component/metadata based

Tags: dxa, 2013, dxa-1.5, brokerquery

How to formulate URLs for application which are component/metadata based ?
How can we query brokerdb to get them

Thanks

Comment: Please share the Tridion version and the let us know if you are using DXA if so what version .provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Tridion version used is SDL Tridion 2013 and DXA 1.5. I am looking to query information from BROKER DB and not from core services or any other way

Comment: Please refer to this link --> https://www.godigitalwithsayantan.com/post/component-link-in-page-metadata-for-dxa-application , see if it helps

Comment: ah, still in Tridion 2013 and DXA 1.5? both versions are retired, what did you try? did you try CIL in-process api libraries to query the broker DB?